# Sort  contacts by different field (not first \ last name)

Tags: contacts, localization

Merging the gmail contacts with the phones address list has many advantages, but also one nagging problem.

While the gmail contacts contain full names, and in English, I want the display name in the dialer to be in Hebrew and I often use nicknames or first names only. Is there some workaround?

The easiest method I can think of is to use another field, such as nickname, for the Hebrew name. But this requires a contact manager that lists contacts by nickname, and not just first \ last name.

Comment: In Gmail, why can't you input your contact in Hebrew to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dw contact manager supports this feature

http://crowdin.net/project/dw-contact-group-manager